# Regex match 2 occurrence with no dots

Tags: regex

**Sample Text**

> 23:00 VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth............
>
> Daily Security Report
>
> SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth........
>   Page 10 of 12
>
> VPN Usage
>
> Site-to-Site IPSec Tunnels by Bandwidth
>
> #
>
> Tunnel
>
> No matching log data for this report
>
> Client-to-Site IPSec Tunnels by Bandwidth
>
> Duration
>
> Traffic Out
>
> Traffic In
>
> IP
>
> No matching log data for this report
>
> SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth
>
> #
>
> 1
>
> User
>
> user.z
>
> 134566
>
> admin_ex
>
> admin
>
> user.b
>
> user.a
>
> IP
>
> Final Report IP

**Goal to parse**

> user.z
>
> 134566
>
> admin_ex
>
> admin
>
> user.b
>
> user.a

**Current State of the solution**

I have this regex : `(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth).*?(?=IP)`
and works if there *is **no*** first occurrence of the **SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Banwidth** string but when I have it on file the regex fail, is anyway to get only the second match ?

Comment: Maybe so - `(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth)(?!\.).*?(?=IP)`? Or `(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth\n).*?(?=IP)` - https://regex101.com/r/yO2hW6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 occurrences of `SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth` - one followed with dots and another with a linebreak.

Just add a line break to your lookahead:

```
(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth\n).*?(?=IP)
                                     ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO2hW6/1)

Or, use a negative lookahead failing the match if there is a dot after:

```
(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth)(?!\.).*?(?=IP)
                                      ^^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO2hW6/2)

If you can access submatches (groups), it is recommended to switch to a capturing group based regex:

```
^SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth\s+(.*?)\nIP$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yO2hW6/3)

Comment: thanks how can I add to my regex the (gms) I see on regex101?

Comment: What is the environment you are using the regex in?

Comment: osx + python 2.7 :

`m = re.findall(r"^SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth\s+(.*?)\nIP$", text)`

Comment: yep done it thank you:

re.findall(r"(?<=SSL-VPN Tunnel Users by Bandwidth\n).*?(?=IP)(?sm)", text)